# Azure API Permission Fix

Tags: python, azure, azure-sdk, azure-sdk-python

When trying to create a security group through the azure python sdk, I get this permissions issue: `msrest.exceptions.ValidationError: Parameter 'SecurityRule.access' can not be None.` How should I fix this permissions issue through the azure web console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to my understanding, you want to use python sdk to create an Azure Network security group. You can use the following script:

```
    from azure.common.credentials import ServicePrincipalCredentials
    from azure.mgmt.compute import ComputeManagementClient
    from azure.mgmt.network import NetworkManagementClient
    from azure.mgmt.network.v2017_03_01.models import NetworkSecurityGroup
    from azure.mgmt.network.v2017_03_01.models import SecurityRule
    from azure.mgmt.resource.resources import ResourceManagementClient

    subscription_id = 'xxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
    credentials = ServicePrincipalCredentials(
        client_id = 'xxxxxx-xxxx-xxx-xxxx-xxxxxxx',
        secret = 'xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxx',
        tenant = 'xxxxxx-xxxxxxx'
    )

    network_client = NetworkManagementClient(
        credentials,
        subscription_id
    )

    resource_client = ResourceManagementClient(
        credentials,
        subscription_id
    )

    resource_client.providers.register('Microsoft.Network')

    resource_group_name = 'test-rg'


    async_security_rule = network_client.security_rules.create_or_update(
    resource_group_name,
    security_group_name,
    new_security_rule_name,
    {
            'access':azure.mgmt.network.v2017_03_01.models.SecurityRuleAccess.allow,
            'description':'New Test security rule',
            'destination_address_prefix':'*',
            'destination_port_range':'123-3500',
            'direction':azure.mgmt.network.v2017_03_01.models.SecurityRuleDirection.inbound,
            'priority':400,
            'protocol':azure.mgmt.network.v2017_03_01.models.SecurityRuleProtocol.tcp,
            'source_address_prefix':'*',
            'source_port_range':'655',
    }
)

security_rule = async_security_rule.result()
```

For more details, please refer to the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-mgmt-network/azure.mgmt.network.v2017_03_01.operations.securityrulesoperations?view=azure-python#create-or-update-resource-group-name--network-security-group-name--security-rule-name--security-rule-parameters--custom-headers-none--raw-false--polling-true----operation-config-)